# Remove outside of bezier path

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a function where I fill the image with a color and use a `UIBezierPath` to erase a point for corners.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);

// Fill image
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

// Round corners
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:15.0];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
[bezierPath stroke];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

With the above, I get an image that does have the Bézier path cut out, and the background filled. 
[image: Icon with Bézier path cut out]

However, how can I remove the corners outside of the path, or get at least some way to reference where they are so I can clear them?

Comment: Rather than stroking the path, you should mask the image to that path.

Comment: BTW, do really need to create image with rounded corners, because if you just want the rounded corners in the UI, you could just set the `cornerRadius` of the view's `layer`.

Comment: @Rob I sadly can't change the view itself with the way I'm doing this, so I have to use the image. Thank you though, I'll check out masking.

Comment: @Rob I tried getting the UIImage from the current context, creating a new context, and applying the bezier's path there, but that didn't do anything (in fact, it made the entire image clear). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Use CoreGraphics, like you have, but clip it to a path:

   ```
   CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0);
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);

   // Round corners
   UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:15.0];
   CGContextAddPath(context, bezierPath.CGPath);
   CGContextClip(context);

   // Fill image
   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
   CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   ```
2. Alternatively, eliminate CoreGraphics and just `fill` the `UIBezierPath`:

   ```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0);
   [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
   [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:15.0] fill];
   UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   ```

Note, in both of those examples, I used `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, supplying a scale of `0` (a scale optimized for display on the device in question). If you really want, you can supply a scale of `1`, which obviously will be a bit pixelated when rendered on a retina device, but that's up to you.

Comment: The latter worked perfectly in my instance, thank you!